# Put an icon inside a circle

Tags: material-ui, react-typescript

[image]

I am doing a project, but this project has a verification email page, and I want to put an email icon at the beginning of this interface, but around a circle and I could not?
How can I put an icon around a circle?

Comment: which Framework or language ?

Comment: react/Typescript @Abir Ahsan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an Icon Avatar. [Documentation here.](https://material-ui.com/components/avatars/#icon-avatars)

[Here's a working CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-icon-avatar-example-5b8uk)

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import EmailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Email';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[50],
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.info.main}`,
    color: theme.palette.info.main,
  },
}));

export default function EmailAvatar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
      <EmailIcon />
    </Avatar>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want the circle color to be transparent. How can I change your code?
That is, I want it to be around the icon without color.
Just the blue line?

Comment: That's what this code does. Did you check the CodeSandbox I linked?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a button - Put the Icon component inside `IconButton` and apply border for it.

```json
emailIconButton: {
  border: "solid 2px", // Color will be detected from IconButton color prop
}
```

If not, just wrap it with a div and apply simple border styles for it.

JSS example:

```json
emailIconWrapper: {
  padding: theme.spacing(1.5),
  borderRadius: "50%",
  borderStyle: "solid",
  borderWidth: "2px",
  borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
}
```

CSS example:

```css
.email-icon-wrapper {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: lightblue;
}
```